# CPU usage in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Win Server 2012 PC and a Win 10 PC. On both of them i have a script to check cpu usage each second and then write it into a file. What I'm curious about is why does the script work on Win Server but not on Win 10 ? Here's the command in the script that im using :

```
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).LoadPercentage >> CPU_LOG.txt
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

Works on WinServer, but not on Win 10, on Win 10 the output file is empty.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Checking CPU usage every second and writing it into a file inevitably invokes a Heisenbergian problem. Making the measurement is affecting the result. Anyway, the obvious thing to check is whether the WMI service is running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the service is running properly. I am able to read RAM info but not cpu.

Comment: This is what i get : https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2016/03/08/NLP7.png